# importing filemaker pro database to postgreSQL via ODBC driver

Tags: database, postgresql, filemaker

I want to import an existing FilemakerPro (local, no server version) database into PostgreSQL. I have configured my two ODBC drivers for FMP and PostgreSQL. The two appear in the ODBC Manager and they are connected properly. Now my problem: I don't find any comprehensible explanation how to import the database in Postgre! I imagine that I need to write a bit of SQL-code but I didn't find any commented one.

I have seen a lot of inormation like this: "I suggest looking at FileMaker ODBC to extract data, or using Postgres ODBC driver and insert data from FileMaker with "Execute SQL" script step into PostgreSQL tables." But nothing that explained more precisely.

Could anybody help me by telling what to do inside PostgreSQL to import the database?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You do not need both drivers, one would be enough. With postgres driver you can push data from FilerMaker, with FileMaker driver you can pull data from FileMaker database. You only need FileMaker ODBC install, since you want to pull data into PostgreSQL.

Comment: I do not see a simple solution for ODBC import into PostgresSQL. There are some commercial tools doing this, but you might be better off using FileMaker "Execute SQL" as it is free. Another simple option is to export all tables as CSV files from FileMaker and import them into PostreSQL.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I will try the "Execute SQL" and if not rebuild my Database and import the by CSV :( In fact, I wished to find a way that enables me to update the postgre-Database from time to time without refreshing each table on its own...

Comment: In this case you should look up FileMaker syncing solutions, e.g. 360Works MirrorSync, although this one needs JDBC set up for both dbms.

Comment: I started looking but it seems rather expensive... thanks however

Comment: You can automate FMP ExecuteSQL with PostgreSQL ODBC driver. Instead of looking for PostgreSQL integration, just search for FileMaker ODBC integration